# PiTFT "Click" event X.org buildroot

Tags: raspberry-pi, touchscreen, buildroot

I have been busy with the PiTFT and added the following wiki on github: https://github.com/Junky2008/Buildroot_PiTFT.
I still have a problem though. As in the wiki, the screen, touch and X.org server work. I have calibrated the touchscreen and i can move the mousepointer in X. What doesn't work is a "click" I can only move the mouse but not click any items.

Is there a driver I should install to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I fixed it! apparently I was using an old version of the STMPE kernel module, I will set everything in my wiki!
https://github.com/Junky2008/Buildroot_PiTFT

I will mark this answer as "the answer" when I updated my wiki